# Regex : replace url inside string

Tags: python, string, url, replace

i have

```
string = 'Server:xxx-zzzzzzzzz.eeeeeeeeeee.frPIPELININGSIZE'
```

i need a python regex expression to identify `xxx-zzzzzzzzz.eeeeeeeeeee.fr` to do a sub-string function to it

**Expected output :**

```
string : 'Server:PIPELININGSIZE'
```

the URL is inside a string, i tried a lot of regex expressions

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Is the string you want to replace always `xxx-zzzzzzzzz.eeeeeeeeeee.fr` or does the regex need to handle more strings to replace?

Comment: it can be shorter but it is always eather a sub-link ee.aa.fr without https or a link without https aa.fr

Comment: I can recommend this website to test your regex. https://regexr.com/  The sub-link structure you describe is not clear enough to me to make a regex for you yet. If you want more help, please give multiple examples of what a sublink can be in your post.

Comment: FYI: That is _not_ a URL. At most, it is a _host name_.

Answer (score 0):

No regex. single line use just to split on your target word.

```
string = 'Server:xxx-zzzzzzzzz.eeeeeeeeeee.frPIPELININGSIZE'

last = string.split("fr",1)[1]

first =string[:string.index(":")]
print(f'{first} : {last}')
```

Gives #

```
Server:PIPELININGSIZE
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, because your question was quite vaguely formulated. :)

```
import re

string = 'Server:xxx-zzzzzzzzz.eeeeeeeeeee.frPIPELININGSIZE'

string_1 = re.search('[a-z.-]+([A-Z]+)', string).group(1)

print(f'string: Server:{string_1}')
```

Output:

```
string: Server:PIPELININGSIZE
```

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the question suggests that you wish to find the hostname in the string, but the expected output suggests that you want to remove it. The following regular expression will create a tuple and allow you to do either.

```
import re

str = "Server:xxx-zzzzzzzzz.eeeeeeeeeee.frPIPELININGSIZE"

p = re.compile('^([A-Za-z]+[:])(.*?)([A-Z]+)$')
m = re.search(p, str)
result = m.groups()
# ('Server:', 'xxx-zzzzzzzzz.eeeeeeeeeee.fr', 'PIPELININGSIZE')
```

Remove the hostname:

```
print(f'{result[0]} {result[2]}')
# Output: 'Server: PIPELININGSIZE'
```

Extract the hostname:

```
print(result[1])
# Output: 'xxx-zzzzzzzzz.eeeeeeeeeee.fr'
```